# Collection with sub - collection

Tags: vb.net, collections

Lets suppose I have forum with one thread with 3 posts.

I want to get this final result:

```
Dim MyFourm As new Fourm
MyFourm.Thread.Add(545)''for ex 545 mean Thread ID.

MyForum.Thread(0).Post(1).Username
```

Thread should be collection of integer(=Thread ID)
 Post should be collection of Post type
* i dont want to use Dictionary

So in this case, the code say something like "chose first thread, and the second post and retrieve username of who write this post".

After playing little bit, i write this code:

```
Public Class MainFrm
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim MyForum As New Forum
        MyForum.Thread.Add(500)' some id's
        MyForum.Thread.Add(120) 

        MyForum.Thread(0).Posts.Add(New ForumPost() With {.PostContent = "Therad ID: 500 | Post: 1#", .Username = "Don"})
        MyForum.Thread(0).Posts.Add(New ForumPost() With {.PostContent = "Therad ID: 500 | Post: 2#", .Username = "Shon"})
        MyForum.Thread(0).Posts.Add(New ForumPost() With {.PostContent = "Therad ID: 500 | Post: 3#", .Username = "Ron"})

        MyForum.Thread(1).Posts.Add(New ForumPost() With {.PostContent = "Therad ID: 120 | Post 1#", .Username = "Emi"})


        For iThread = 0 To MyForum.Thread.Count - 1
            For iPost = 0 To MyForum.Thread(iThread).Posts.Count - 1
                Static Pst As New ForumPost
                Pst = MyForum.Thread(iThread).Posts(iPost)
                Console.WriteLine($"Content:{Pst.PostContent}, Username who post it:{Pst.Username}")
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Forum
    Public Property Thread As New ThreadCollection

End Class

Public Class ForumThread
    Inherits List(Of Integer)
    Public Property Posts As New PostCollection
    Sub New(id As Integer)

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ThreadCollection
    Inherits List(Of ForumThread)
    Public Overloads Sub Add(ByVal id As Integer)
        MyBase.Add(New ForumThread(id))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ForumPost
    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property PostContent As String
End Class

Public Class PostCollection
    Inherits List(Of ForumPost)
End Class



 '   Content:Therad ID: 500 | Post: 1#, Username who post it:Don
 '  Content:Therad ID: 500 | Post: 2#, Username who post it:Shon
 '  Content:Therad ID: 500 | Post: 3#, Username who post it:Ron
 '   Content:Therad ID: 120 | Post 1#, Username who post it:Emi
```

Its working fine, but my question if its write well? Or its possible to improve it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Your types should look something like this:

```
Public Class Post

    Public Property Username As String

    'Other members

End Class

Public Class Thread

    Private _posts As New List(Of Post)

    Public ReadOnly Property Posts As List(Of Post)
        Get
            Return _posts
        End Get
    End Property

    'Other members

End Class

Public Class Forum

    Private _threads As New List(Of Thread)

    Public ReadOnly Property Threads As List(Of Thread)
        Get
            Return _threads
        End Get
    End Property

    'Other members

End Class
```

That's the pattern used throughout the .NET Framework, e.g. `myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(1).Item(2)`.

In VB 2015, those last two classes can be collapsed to this:

```
Public Class Thread

    Public ReadOnly Property Posts As List(Of Post) = New List(Of Post)

    'Other members

End Class

Public Class Forum

    Public ReadOnly Property Threads As List(Of Thread) = New List(Of Thread)

    'Other members

End Class
```

If you want custom functionality then you should inherit the `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)` class rather than `List(Of T)` and then declare your properties of that type, e.g.

```
Public Class Thread

    Public ReadOnly Property Id As Integer

    Public ReadOnly Property Posts As List(Of Post) = New List(Of Post)

    Public Sub New(id As Integer)
        Me.Id = id
    End Sub

    'Other members

End Class

Public Class ThreadCollection
    Inherits Collection(Of Thread)

    Public Sub AddNew(id As Integer)
        Me.Add(New Thread(id))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Forum

    Public ReadOnly Property Threads As ThreadCollection = New ThreadCollection

    'Other members

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you. its what i looking for.

Comment: If this answer has solved your problem then please make sure to accept it.